# How do I use a test nickname to sign in into Amazon Game Circle?

Tags: android, amazon-gamecircle

I'm integrating Amazon GameCircle Leaderboards and Achievements into my game. I have set up everything in "Mobile App Distribution portal" and I have done everything described in "Initializing GameCircle in Your Game". Now, `AmazonGamesCallback` calls back `onServiceReady` that means successfull initialization.

My question is: how do I (as a game player) log-in to Game Circle? I have registered a test nickname in "Mobile App Distribution portal" and I guess I must log-in with this name somehow?

The documentation states:

> "Your customers see a list of GameCircle features in the welcome message when your game starts and in your game's sign in page."

What is my game's sign in page? Have I missed anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it on kindle fire emulator.
AFAIK you are already logged in the GameCircle, if you are on registered amazon device device, but your nickname is generated.

What nickname was generated on device I found by showing Leaderboards from my game, then click the ball button (GameCircle) in top left corner, Then in GameCircle section click on Your Profile and there you will see if you are in Guest mode or if not, there is your generated nickname for this device.

Next I just added that nickname to test nicknames in Amazon Game Circle web settings and everything worked fine.

if you have trouble using Kindle Fire Emulator and Game Circle, check out this FAQ:

> GameCircle Does Not Show Account Data Even When Emulator Is Registered
>   to an Amazon Account
>
> After you register the emulator to an Amazon account, GameCircle 2.0
>   may show a guest account, or not show an account at all. GameCircle
>   features such as Leaderboard and Achievements do not display the
>   GameCircle data for the Amazon account. To remedy these issues, close
>   the emulator window and restart the AVD, and make sure that you clear
>   the Wipe user data check box.

https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/ki-emulator.html